# How to query Foreman for hosts with a specific Global Parameter?

Tags: foreman, puppet-foreman

We make some use of the Global Parameters in Foreman, and I need to list all hosts, which have the Global Parameter `foo` set to "`bar`".

Can I do that with the REST API or via some other method? Going through the [list of API-calls](https://theforeman.org/api/1.14/), I do not find anything applicable -- is there hope?

---

*Alternatively*, I'm thinking of creating a special Puppet-class, which will do nothing but restate the global parameters as its own variables. By making it an [exported resource](http://www.masterzen.fr/2009/03/08/all-about-puppet-storeconfigs/), I may be able to collect the data from all hosts... Seems nasty, however -- is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I do that with the REST API or via some other method? Going through the list of API-calls, I do not find anything applicable -- is there hope?

You want `GET /api/v2/hosts` ([API doc](https://theforeman.org/api/1.14/apidoc/v2/hosts/index.html)) to retrieve a list of hosts, then add the `search` parameter to filter the result.

Use `search=params.foo=bar` to filter for the `foo` parameter. You can find other search strings through the UI search autocomplete (it's exactly the same syntax) and more information's in [Foreman manual: Searching](https://theforeman.org/manuals/1.14/index.html#4.1.5Searching).

So, the full URL to query would be something like:

```
https://foreman.example.com/api/v2/hosts?search=params.foo=bar
```